# Как менять контекст запланированного уведомления в AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager, android-push-notification

У меня есть уведомление запланированное на 8:00(использую AlarmManager), его текст = "у тебя 1 новое дело". Мне надо изменить его текст на "у тебя 2 новых дела" и т.д.. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вроде бы никак нельзя. Точно можно отменить текущий AlarmManager и создать новый. А возможно, стоит сделать так, чтобы в нужное время данные для уведомления брались из БД, например. Тогда можно было бы только в БД поменять значения и они бы в нужное время отобразились бы. Но тут надо ещё смотреть как у вас уведомление создаётся с текущим текстом - могут нюансы возникнуть.

Comment: А что мне использовать, чтобы считать данные из БД и создать уведомление, когда приложение закрыто?

Comment: мне кажется что для таких целей существует firebase, там и бд можно юзать, но нужен будет интернет)

Comment: Не знаю, как сейчас у вас сделано, так напишу как бы я сделал: 1. AlarmManager стартует BroadcastReceiver. 2.1. BroadcastReceiver стартует сервис, если запрос в БД ожидается дольше 5 секунд. 2.2. Если ожидается, что исполнится быстро - BroadcastReceiver  идёт в БД/префы, берёт оттуда инофрмацию и отображает уведомление.